# asp.net Remove item from dictionary in session from client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, dictionary

I am writing an application where a series of "windows" divs are being generated. In order to track open "windows" I am using a dictionary held in the session. As these "windows" are being generated from Gridview selections, I am using the server side event to also update the dictionary, as follows:

```
    Shared Function setWindowsObject(WindowReference As String, WindowTitle As String) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim windowList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        windowList = getWindowsObject("")
        windowList.Add(WindowReference, WindowTitle)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("UIWindowCollection") = windowList
        result = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = False
    End Try
    Return result

End Function

Shared Function getWindowsObject(ByVal filter As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim windowList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    If HttpContext.Current.Session("UIWindowCollection") Is Nothing Then
    Else
        windowList = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("UIWindowCollection"), Dictionary(Of String, String))
        If Not filter & "" = "" Then
            Dim windowListTemp As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In windowList
                If entry.Key.StartsWith(filter) Then
                    windowListTemp.Add(Replace(entry.Key, " ", ""), entry.Value)
                End If
            Next
            windowList = windowListTemp
        End If
    End If
    Return windowList

End Function
```

This works great and I am able to bind to this dictionary. However, I need to remove one of these value when a "window" is destroyed but because the window management is handled client side, I do not have a server side event to capture the value to remove, remove it from the dictionary and reinsert the new dictionary into the session then rebind it to the grid. So I need to find a client side solution if one exists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use a `WebMethod` which is called from the window's `onbeforeunload` event, there you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session` to access the sssion and to remove it from the dictionary.

Comment: I tried using a webmethod as follows:

` function OnClientCloseHandler(sender, args) {
                PageMethods.RemoveWindow(sender);
            }

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
    Public Shared Function RemoveWindow(window As String) As String
        Dim myWindow As String = window
        Return myWindow
    End Function  `

But I get a console error of: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - Before it hits the Web Method. If I remove this then no error so it's definitely this overflowing the stack. Can't see why though

Comment: No idea. Is that a telerik control, i'm not familiar with it. What is the `sender` you're passing as string to  `RemoveWindow`? What happens if you put a `alert(sender)` before you call `RemoveWindow`, what is the output?

Comment: It is a telerik control, yes. Sender is the value of the window and if I console.log and the output is as expected. I've commented out the PageMethods.RemoveWindow  portion and the code executes quickly as you'd expect given the load and without error. As soon as I add in the PageMethods line, closing the window hangs and then I get the error. Apologies for the non formatted responses but I couldn't get the whole markdown to work properly

Comment: Ok. It's passing just sender that it doesn't like. I can invoke the web method if I just pass hardcoded string. So looks like I have to drill into sender a little more. Thanks for your responses.